# Add custom login form to hapi-auth-basic

Tags: node.js, security, hapi.js

I use [hapi-auth-basic](https://www.npmjs.com/package/hapi-auth-basic) to authenticate users. My question is how to add custom login form instead of using the basic form of the browser.

Answer (score 2):

You can bind the functionality of `hapi-auth-basic` to any custom login form. You need to make sure that the properties get evaluated correctly on server side.

Here's a dedicated tutorial on [basic authentication in hapi with hapi-auth-basic](https://futurestud.io/tutorials/hapi-basic-authentication-with-username-and-password).

Let's say you've a form like this: (it's very simple for illustration purposes)

```
<form action="/login" method="post">
  <input type="text" name="username">
  <input type="text" name="password">

  <input type="submit" value="Log in">
</form>
```

On server side, you need to have multiple things in place:

- an authentication strategy with a `validateFunc` that takes the input and evaluates it against your data set (like database)
- a route handler for method `POST` on path `/login`, because the form sends the data to this endpoint
- the `auth` config set with your strategy at the route handler

What I mean is a setup like this: (again, simplified)

```
server.auth.strategy('simple', 'basic', { validateFunc: (request, username, password, callback) => {} })

server.route({
  method: 'GET',
  path: '/private-route',
  config: {
    auth: 'simple',
    handler: function (request, reply) {
      reply('Yeah! This message is only available for authenticated users!')
    }
  }
})
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: I tried the exemple in the tutorial but i still need the instruction that redirect to login page soi think that we need a route handler for method GET on path /login.